# Scraping 13F filings from SEC using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, sec

I'm trying to scrape the data in the SEC FORM 13-F Information Table from the following link:

https://sec.report/Document/0001567619-21-010281/

I tried the below script:

```
library(timetk)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://sec.report/Document/0001567619-21-010281/"
url <- read_html(url)
raw_data <- url %>%
  html_nodes("#table td") %>%
  html_text()
```

However, I'm unable to get the data components and under values, it says that `raw_data` is empty. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the fmpcloudr package.

Answer (score 0):

The data is present in the response. You can use a CSS [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector to target the nested table. You will need to decide what to decide with the initial three rows which need to be transformed into a single header most likely (or not!)

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

page <- read_html("https://sec.report/Document/0001567619-21-010281/")

table <- page %>%
  html_node('[summary="Form 13F-NT Header Information"]') %>%
  html_table(fill = T)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use 13F from html page it is much easier here is an example

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import numpy as np


# Makes a request to the url
url="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1541617/000154161721000009/xslForm13F_X01/altcap13f3q21infotable.xml"
request = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

# Pass the html response into read_html
tables = pd.read_html(request.text)
df = tables[3]
```

Comment: The language used in the original question is R. This answer is in python.